# Most common character in a string

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

> Write a function that takes a string consisting of alphabetic
>   characters as input argument and returns the most common character.
>   Ignore white spaces i.e. Do not count any white space as a character.
>   Note that capitalization does not matter here i.e. that a lower case
>   character is equal to a upper case character. In case of a tie between
>   certain characters return the last character that has the most count

**This is the updated code**

```
def most_common_character (input_str):
    input_str = input_str.lower()
    new_string = "".join(input_str.split())
    print(new_string)
    length = len(new_string)
    print(length)
    count = 1
    j = 0
    higher_count = 0
    return_character = ""
    for i in range(0, len(new_string)):
        character = new_string[i]
        while (length - 1):
            if (character == new_string[j + 1]):
                count += 1
            j += 1
            length -= 1    
            if (higher_count < count):
                higher_count = count
    return (character)     

#Main Program
input_str = input("Enter a string: ")
result = most_common_character(input_str)
print(result)
```

The above is my code. I am getting an error of `string index out of bound` which I can't understand why. Also the code only checks the occurrence of first character I am confused about how to proceed to the next character and take the maximum count?

**The error i get when I run my code:**

```
> Your answer is NOT CORRECT Your code was tested with different inputs.
> For example when your function is called as shown below:
> 
> most_common_character ('The cosmos is infinite')
> 
> ############# Your function returns ############# e The returned variable type is: type 'str'
> 
> ######### Correct return value should be ######## i The returned variable type is: type 'str'
> 
> ####### Output of student print statements ###### thecosmosisinfinite 19
```

Comment: It's more easier with `Dictionary` I think

Comment: I don't know how to use a dictionary. I am a beginner in python.

Comment: please format your code: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35594767/revisions

Comment: If you got this question from the mooc or chuck severances course the answer is in the video.

Comment: Yep, it is from MOOC.

Comment: http://www.pythonlearn.com/#panel17d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code is *almost* correct. You need to move `count`, `j`, `length` inside of your `for i in range(0, len(new_string))` because you need to start over on each iteration and also if `count` is greater than `higher_count`, you need to save that `charater` as `return_character` and return it instead of `character` which is always last char of your string because of `character = new_string[i]`.

I don't see why have you used `j+1` and `while length-1`. After correcting them, it now covers tie situations aswell.

```
def most_common_character (input_str):
    input_str = input_str.lower()
    new_string = "".join(input_str.split())
    higher_count = 0
    return_character = ""

    for i in range(0, len(new_string)):
        count = 0
        length = len(new_string)
        j = 0
        character = new_string[i]
        while length > 0:
            if (character == new_string[j]):
                count += 1
            j += 1
            length -= 1    
            if (higher_count <= count):
                higher_count = count
                return_character = character
    return (return_character)
```

Comment: note: it is `O(n**2)` in time `O(1)` in space algorithm. It can be implemented in `O(n)` in time instead e.g., [using `collections.Counter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35608206/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I was just trying to debug and fix(had so many free time) OPs code so didn't changed much. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex patter to search for all characters.  `\w` matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  The `+` after `[\w]` means to match one or more repetitions.

Finally, you use Counter to total them and `most_common(1)` to get the top value. See below for the case of a tie.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

s = "Write a function that takes a string consisting of alphabetic characters as input argument and returns the most common character. Ignore white spaces i.e. Do not count any white space as a character. Note that capitalization does not matter here i.e. that a lower case character is equal to a upper case character. In case of a tie between certain characters return the last character that has the most count"

>>> Counter(c.lower() for c in re.findall(r"\w", s)).most_common(1)
[('t', 46)]
```

In the case of a tie, it is a little more tricky.

```
def top_character(some_string):
    joined_characters = [c for c in re.findall(r"\w+", some_string.lower())]
    d = Counter(joined_characters)
    top_characters = [c for c, n in d.most_common() if n == max(d.values())]
    if len(top_characters) == 1:
        return top_characters[0]
    reversed_characters = joined_characters[::-1]  
    for c in reversed_characters:
        if c in top_characters:
            return c

>>> top_character(s)
't'

>>> top_character('the the')
'e'
```

In the case of your code above and your sentence "The cosmos is infinite", you can see that 'i' occurs more frequently that 'e' (the output of your function):

```
>>> Counter(c.lower() for c in "".join(re.findall(r"[\w]+", 'The cosmos is infinite'))).most_common(3)
[('i', 4), ('s', 3), ('e', 2)]
```

You can see the issue in your code block:

```
for i in range(0, len(new_string)):
    character = new_string[i]
    ...
return (character)
```

You are iterating through a sentence and assign that letter to the variable character, which is never reassigned elsewhere.  The variable `character` will thus always return the last character in your string.

Comment: 1- `"".join(re.findall(r"[\w]+", s)))` is redundant. You could use `re.findall(r'\w', s)`. Note: `\w` matches more than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (the question has Python 3 tag). Though it is unnecessary: all non-whitespace characters are alphabetic here i.e., `''.join(s.split())` could be used instead. 2- Use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` for case-insensitive comparison of Unicode strings 3- In case of a tie, you could [use `OrderedDict`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35608206/4279)

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the "tie" requirement; [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) works:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def most_common_character(input_str):
    return Counter(chain(*input_str.casefold().split())).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Example:

```
>>> most_common_character('The cosmos is infinite')
'i'
>>> most_common_character('ab' * 3)
'a'
```

To return the last character that has the most count, we could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

def most_common_character(input_str):
    counter = OrderedCounter(chain(*input_str.casefold().split()))
    return max(reversed(counter.items()), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Example:

```
>>> most_common_character('ab' * 3)
'b'
```

Note: this solution assumes that [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) returns the first character that has the most count (and therefore there is a [`reversed()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), to get the last one) and all characters are single Unicode codepoints. In general, you might want to use `\X` regular expression (supported by [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)), to extract ["user-perceived characters"](http://unicode.org/glossary/#user_perceived_character) ([eXtended grapheme cluster](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)) from the Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common_character(s):
    char_count = Counter(s)
    return char_count.most_common(1)[0][0]

# Example
string21 = "programming is fun"
common_char = most_common_character(string21)
print("Most Common Character:", common_char)
```

#Output = r