# Find rare characters with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

Assume I have a huge `.txt` file full of random characters and I want to find out the "rare ones". Is there some module (something at all, actually) in Python (possibly, version `3.x`, but I have also a machine using Python `2.7`, in case it's better) written for this purpose? In case of positive answer, where can I find some basic explanation of its functioning?
Thank you very much.

Comment: By _rare ones_ you meant low in count?

Comment: It may be too much, but you could use scipy module to do some statistical analysis. I haven't use it myself, but as far as I know it should contain functionalities that you require. And it works ok with python 3.x and 2.x.

Comment: @Jason: Jeah, actually I mean something like: their (average) number of occurrences is (significantly) lower than the one of other characters. Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Szworny: thanks, but the statistical analysis was exactly what I wanted to avoid using... I'm looking for something really quick and "not heavy" (if it exists!).

Comment: You can try the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) module. This will fetch the count for each character. The rest of the calculations you'll have to do on your own.

Comment: You could implement your own algorithm that would map character => its count using `Dict`. Then, using a for loop you could iterate through an array of characters incrementing the counter for each char and to get the result filter out the keys which holds values bigger than some threshold. Or just use the approach @JasonEstibeiro mentioned :)

Comment: If you want to perform more complex calculations, then you can have a look at [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [`scipy`](http://www.scipy.org) modules.

Comment: Thanks both for the interesting suggestions, I'll try to figure out a solution starting from this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter("text")
print(c.most_common())
```

output

```
[('t', 2), ('e', 1), ('x', 1)]
```

Comment: The OP asked for rare, not most common.

Comment: @Duncan just reverse the list.

Comment: @Duncan They're equal, just different order.

Comment: I know that, just think the answer is incomplete unless it actually says it.

Comment: @Duncan: the rarest char is: `c.most_common()[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
for c in open(filename, "r").read():
    if c in d:
        d[c] += 1
    else:
        d[c] = 1

print(d)
```

Then you can use `d` to search for the minimum letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this, using a `Counter` dictionary. It prints the rare characters, along with their number of occurrences. We define a rare character to be one whose number of occurrences is less than a certain threshold, which is the mean number of occurrences multiplied by a weighting factor, which I've set to 0.5 in this example.

```
from collections import Counter

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

counter = Counter(text)
mean = len(text) / len(counter)
print('Mean:', mean)

weight = 0.5
thresh = mean * weight
print('Threshold:', thresh)

#Only print results for chars whose occurence is less than the threshold
for ch, count in reversed(counter.most_common()):
    if count <= thresh:
        print('{0!r}: {1}'.format(ch, count))
    else:
        break
```

If this is an actual text file you may wish to filter out certain characters, eg newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `collections` option to access the n least common elements `c.most_common()[:-n-1:-1]`

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter("sadaffdsagfgdfaafsasdfs3213jlkjk22jl31j2k13j313j13")
res = c.most_common()[:-3-1:-1]
print "The 3 Rarest characters are:",res[0][0],",",res[1][0],"and",res[2][0]
```

Result:

```
The 3 Rarest characters are: l , g and k
```

Comment: why sorting sorted list?

Comment: I'm sorting on the numerical value of the occurrence rather than the alphabetical character.

Comment: 1- `.most_common()` already returns the pairs sorted by the number of occurrences e.g., `.most_common()[-1]` is the rarest character -- no need to call additional `sort()`, to get 2 rarest characters. 2- you could use `operator.itemgetter(1)` instead of defining `occur()` function 3- all your strings are bytestrings. You should use Unicode when handling text. 4- [`heapq.nsmallest()` can be more efficient than calling `.most_common()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35799656/4279)

Comment: I meant to say: "strings are bytestrings" *in your code* and you should use Unicode strings instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Altered to fully utilise the functionality with the collections module

Answer (score 1):

To find 10 rarest characters in a text:

```
from collections import Counter

rarest_chars = Counter(text).most_common()[-10:]
```

"character" means a Unicode codepoint here for simplicity: It means `"a"` and `"A"` are considered as *different* characters. It means `u'g̈'` (U+0067 U+0308) is considered as *two* characters. See how these issues are handled in a related question: [Most common character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608206/4279).

`counter.most_common()[-10:]` could be written more efficiently using [`heapq.nsmallest(10, counter.items(), key=itemgetter(1))`](https://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)
: `.items()` returns pairs `(character, its_count)` and [`key=itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) extracts the counts so that `10` pairs with the least counts are returned.